# What does a DME indicator do in HOLD or RNAV mode?

Tags: gnss, radio, radio-navigation, rnav, dme

I found [this DME indicator](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.picclickimg.com%2Fd%2Fl400%2Fpict%2F192915049703_%2FCessna-400-DME-Indicator-ARC-C-476A-44020-1000.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fpicclick.com%2FCessna-400-DME-Indicator-ARC-C-476A-44020-1000-192017897761.html&tbnid=kYt_cT2GI3zxAM&vet=12ahUKEwjZ4eyS77v0AhVTAGMBHUjcBkgQMygGegQIARBE..i&docid=1M29pR--Db96aM&w=400&h=400&itg=1&q=arc%20400%20dme%20switched%20on&client=ubuntu&ved=2ahUKEwjZ4eyS77v0AhVTAGMBHUjcBkgQMygGegQIARBE) on the Cessna 210. Its mode switch has four positions - NAV1, NAV2, RNAV and HOLD. NAV1 and 2 are clear - it uses the NAV1 and 2 freq respectively. I'm wondering what the other two do, especially HOLD ?

RNAV is also quite logical - it uses the position selected in the RNAV selector. But how does the DME indicator determine the distance/speed to the RNAV position ? By using the GPS ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you select and tune NAV 1 or NAV 2  (assuming the NAV 1 or NAV 2 Navaid has associated DME) and then select the "Hold" mode the DME will stay on that frequency after you change the NAV 1 or NAV 2 to another frequency.

Note that the DME hold mode is only associated with NAV 1 and NAV 2.

The RNAV and GPS interface with the 400 DME unit would depend on integrated system compatibility/interoperability.  It's a fairly old system.